# difference between postgres=# and postgres-#?

Tags: php

I am trying to enter command

```
postgres=# select * from emp_data(gives me nothing)
postgres-# select * from emp_data;(again gives me nothing)
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select * from emp_data;

    ^
```

the table is created and exists i can view it in pgadmin

Comment: and the table has records? you selected the correct database?

Comment: yes i did ......the default database is postgres and the table name is emp_data

Answer (score 3):

```
postgres=#
```

means you could start a new command.

```
postgres-#
```

means this is the continuation of the active command. So the command you really entered up to now is

```
select * from emp_data select * from emp_data;
```

which is no valid SQL statement. 
You just forgot the ';' at the end of the statement (first line)

Answer (score 0):

first do check whether that table (emp_data) was exist or not, if it is existed then do check for which schema it was belongs to,then enter
select * from schema_name.table_name;
or if it was belongs to public schema then enter
select * from tablename;

And if you get postgres-# then type control + c,it can take back to you to postgres=# to enter new command.